# Is there a way to pack selected UVs around unselected UVs?

Tags: uv

I want to use the pack option to maximize space in my UVs, but there are some UVs that I'm overlapping to get a repeat of the texture underneath. Is there a way to pack the remaining/non-overlapping UVs around the overlapping ones, so that they all fit without disturbing the coordinates of the overlapped UVs?

If it's relevant, I'm importing this file into something that only allows for a single texture, material, and object, so all UVs have to be on the same map.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should simply select those UV islands you'd like to pack (`L` for selecting whole island, `Shift` + `L` for several, but leaving overlapping UVs unselected) and pack them (`Ctrl` + `A`).

Comment: I should have clarified a little. What you say works but it packs the selected islands to take up all the UV space. I want to pack the remaining UVs around the overlapping ones, leaving room for all.